# parsing log files and finding appropriate delimiters

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

Say I have a log file that looks like this:

```
'2021-05-18T14:01:13Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=11593 userid=1 xid=19771457 ]' LOG: BEGIN;
'2021-05-18T14:01:13Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=11593 userid=1 xid=19771457 ]' LOG: SET datestyle TO ISO;
'2021-05-18T14:01:13Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=11593 userid=1 xid=19771457 ]' LOG: SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY;
'2021-05-18T14:01:13Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=11593 userid=1 xid=19771457 ]' LOG: SET STATEMENT_TIMEOUT TO 300000;
'2021-05-18T14:01:13Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=11593 userid=1 xid=19771457 ]' LOG: /* hash: f71f47211eca32d63469fba576bbbb19 */

SELECT TRIM(application_name) AS application_name
     , MAX(recordtime)        AS last_used
FROM stl_connection_log
WHERE dbname <> 'dev'
  AND username <> 'rdsdb'
  AND (   application_name LIKE 'RedshiftUserLastLogin-v%'
       OR application_name LIKE 'RedshiftSystemTablePersistence-v%'
       OR application_name LIKE 'AnalyzeVacuumUtility-v%'
       OR application_name LIKE 'ColumnEncodingUtility-v%' )
GROUP BY application_name
LIMIT 50
;
'2021-05-18T14:01:13Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=11593 userid=1 xid=19771457 ]' LOG: SELECT btrim( pg_catalog.stll_connection_log.application_name ) AS application_name, MAX(pg_catalog.stll_connection_log.recordtime) AS last_used FROM pg_catalog.stll_connection_log WHERE pg_catalog.stll_connection_log.dbname <> 'dev'::Char(3) AND pg_catalog.stll_connection_log.username <> 'rdsdb'::Char(5) AND (pg_catalog.stll_connection_log.application_name LIKE 'AnalyzeVacuumUtility-v%' OR pg_catalog.stll_connection_log.application_name LIKE 'ColumnEncodingUtility-v%' OR pg_catalog.stll_connection_log.application_name LIKE 'RedshiftSystemTablePersistence-v%' OR pg_cata
```

I want to read in each "row" when it begins with the quote + timestamp. Each row begins with this: `'2021-05-18T14:01:13Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=11593 userid=1 xid=19771457 ]'` (let's call this a row delimiter) and then break apart each row into its appropriate column (query, pid, user, db, etc.). How do I do this in the easiest way possible?

The issue is that the row delimiter does not appear on each newline. As you can see, there is a "row" where the query is on multiple newlines and so when reading the text file in python, I'm worried that there will be several rows without a delimiter. So does this mean that as I read in lines from the file in python, I need to first check if it begins with a row delimiter and if not, continue appending the line to memory until a row delimiter is reached?

Ideally, the row:

```
'2021-05-18T14:01:13Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=11593 userid=1 xid=19771457 ]' LOG: /* hash: f71f47211eca32d63469fba576bbbb19 */

SELECT TRIM(application_name) AS application_name
     , MAX(recordtime)        AS last_used
FROM stl_connection_log
WHERE dbname <> 'dev'
  AND username <> 'rdsdb'
  AND (   application_name LIKE 'RedshiftUserLastLogin-v%'
       OR application_name LIKE 'RedshiftSystemTablePersistence-v%'
       OR application_name LIKE 'AnalyzeVacuumUtility-v%'
       OR application_name LIKE 'ColumnEncodingUtility-v%' )
GROUP BY application_name
LIMIT 50
;
```

is broken up into a csv row where:

```
timestamp = 2021-05-18T14:01:13Z UTC
db = dev
user = rdsdb
pid = 11593
userid = 1
xid = 19771457
query = `SELECT TRIM(application_name) AS application_name, MAX(recordtime AS last_used FROM stl_connection_log WHERE dbname <> 'dev' AND username <> 'rdsdb' AND (application_name LIKE 'RedshiftUserLastLogin-v%' OR application_name LIKE 'RedshiftSystemTablePersistence-v% OR application_name LIKE 'AnalyzeVacuumUtility-v%' OR application_name LIKE 'ColumnEncodingUtility-v%' ) GROUP BY application_name LIMIT 50';
```

and the row:

```
'2021-05-18T14:01:13Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=11593 userid=1 xid=19771457 ]' LOG: BEGIN;
```

is broken up into:

```
timestamp = 2021-05-18T14:01:13Z UTC
db = dev
user = rdsdb
pid = 11593
userid = 1
xid = 19771457
query = `LOG: BEGIN';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to spot lines which are row delimiters, and then use [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby) to read groups of either delimiters or query lines:

```
from itertools import groupby
import re
import csv

row_delim = re.compile(r"'(.*? UTC) \[ db=(.*?) user=(.*?) pid=(.*?) userid=(.*?) xid=(.*?) \]'")

with open('logfile.txt') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(["timestamp", "db", "user", "pid", "userid", "xid", "query"])

    for re_row_delim, lines in groupby(f_input, lambda x: row_delim.match(x)):
        if re_row_delim:
            last_delim = re_row_delim.groups()
        else:
            query = [line.strip() for line in lines if line.strip()]
            row = [*last_delim, ' '.join(query)]
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

This assumes that the ordering of the parameters is constant.

For your given test file, groupby will first return a valid `re_row_delim` holding the result of the regular expression (in the lambda function), `lines` is a list of all the delimiter rows. As they are all the same, we just use the key value itself (i.e. `re_row_delim`) and ignore `lines`.

The next iteration it reads all the lines which do not match, i.e. the query string. In this case `re_row_delim` will be `None` as it failed to match, `lines` now holds all the query lines.

So for each iteration, it alternates between reading all the delimiter lines or all the query lines.

Giving you a CSV file as follows:

```
timestamp,db,user,pid,userid,xid,query
2021-05-18T14:01:13Z UTC,dev,rdsdb,11593,1,19771457,"SELECT TRIM(application_name) AS application_name , MAX(recordtime)        AS last_used FROM stl_connection_log WHERE dbname <> 'dev' AND username <> 'rdsdb' AND (   application_name LIKE 'RedshiftUserLastLogin-v%' OR application_name LIKE 'RedshiftSystemTablePersistence-v%' OR application_name LIKE 'AnalyzeVacuumUtility-v%' OR application_name LIKE 'ColumnEncodingUtility-v%' ) GROUP BY application_name LIMIT 50 ;"
```

---

If you need to also keep the text after `LOG:` on the timestamp lines, then a different approach is needed. The regular expression can capture that text and a `query_start` can hold all the text from each line:

```
from itertools import groupby
import re
import csv

row_delim = re.compile(r"'(.*? UTC) \[ db=(.*?) user=(.*?) pid=(.*?) userid=(.*?) xid=(.*?) \]' LOG: (.*)")
query_start = []    # holds all text after LOG: lines

with open('logfile.txt') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(["timestamp", "db", "user", "pid", "userid", "xid", "query"])

    for re_row_delim, lines in groupby(f_input, lambda x: row_delim.match(x)):
        if re_row_delim:
            last_delim = re_row_delim.groups()[:6]
            query_start.extend([row_delim.match(line).group(7) for line in lines])
        else:
            query = [line.strip() for line in [*query_start, *lines] if line.strip()]
            row = [*last_delim, ' '.join(query)]
            csv_output.writerow(row)
            query_start = []
```

Comment: What do you mean spot lines which are row delimiters? Like identifiy which lines start with row delimiters? Then how do you take all the lines after teh delimiter up until the next row delimiter as one? Sorry could you just clarify what you mean a little... I think you're right but I just need some help clarifying

Comment: I suggest you read about groupby, it groups things together that match a given rule. In this case whether or not a line has the timestamp etc

Comment: So will this capture the queries when the queries are on the same line? For example, the first line has a query of BEGIN. Will that be captured?

Comment: Probably yes, but you'd need to add an example to your question to be sure. It groups all lines which don't  match the regular expression and reduces the lines to a single line.